# Getting Error In installing cwm recovery in Micromax a1(androidOne) from fastboot!

Tags: fastboot

I want to install cwm recovery in my canvas a1 for backup my current rom android 4.4.4.
I m going to install lollipop 5.1 I heard about some bug in lollipop so for my safety i want a backup.
I used minimal adb and fastboot for installing cwm.
But when i type the command "**fastboot flash recovery recovery.img**"
End hit enter
Then it show a error.
"**Failed (remote download for partition 'recovery' is not allowed**'

[image: Error Screenshot]

What should i do now?

Comment: Have you unlocked the bootloader?

Answer (score 1):

Your recovery partition is locked.

1. Make yourself a developer (go to Settings -> About Phone -> Tap on Build until developer
2. In Developer options turn on Enable OEM unlock
3. Flash the new recovery, don forget to "fastboot oem unlock"
4. Important: don't allow phone to complete a normal reboot after flash. When rebooting, press Vol Up + Vol Down + Power to enter CWM recovery directly. Otherwise the stock recovery will replace CWM again.

Comment: The first line is incorrect. It is not the recovery partition which is locked  but the bootloader is. See https://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/ABS%20Lollipop%20MR1%20Verified%20Boot.pdf#10 for more info. `fastboot oem unlock` unlocks the bootloader, not the recovery partition. :)